# How to construct Elasticsearch 'Searchhit' object from a JSON string in JAVA

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm using `Elasticsearch 5.1.1` in my project. After I send a search query via RESTful API, I can get a result `JSON` string from the cluster. I'm wondering if there is a convenient way to convert that `JSON` string to a `Java` object(such as `SearchResponse` or `SearchHit` provided in `Elasticsearch` package) so that I can fetch all result documents and some meta info easily?

I tried to use `TransportClient` provided by `Elasticsearch` itself. It can return the result as an `SearchResponse` object, but it seemed that it can only perform search via `/_search` API. What I expected to use is `/_sql` API provided by a [SQL plugin](https://github.com/NLPchina/elasticsearch-sql/). So how can I do this?